# How does a bump or notch in a converging nozzle affect downstream flow?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Say we have a converging nozzle with a bump or step at its inlet, as shown in this schematic:

[image: Fig 1 Converging Nozzle with Step]

How does the bump affect the flow at the nozzle exit? Assuming steady state, incompressible, and isentropic flow.

I'm thinking that if the flow is laminar, the effective area of the nozzle decreases to match the step, like in the figure below:

[image: Fig 2]

Is this correct? How would I go about quantifying this? e.g. x step height causes the nozzle exit to be effectively reduced to diameter y

How might turbulence affect this system?

Thanks for taking the time to read this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out vena contracta.

Answer (score 0):

at low speeds, the fluid flow will flow up the inlet side of the notch, turn the corner, and flow down the other side on its way out the nozzle.

at high speeds the flow will separate in the inlet corner of the notch base, producing a swirl or dead zone there, and will also produce a swirl immediately behind the notch (called a *turbulent wake*). these zones represent *flow separation* where the stream lines of the flow field do not follow the contours of the nozzle.

The transition between attached flow and detached flow is set by a number called the *Reynolds number*. For Reynolds numbers below a certain threshold, the flow is *laminar* (following the nozzle profile without separation) and above it, the flow is *turbulent* (separation occurs).